# @ConfigurationProperties usage in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a project built up on struts framework but I've integrated *Spring Framework* in same(using a `servlet-config.xml`) and using the *MVC* and *AOP* in it, now in one requirement I must use one project which is built up on *SpringBoot* and using `@ConfigurationProperties` binding an `application.yml` file with a POJO.

I just need to use the code of that project and hence added the dependency of that project. Is there any way I can use `@ConfigurationProperties` to bind the POJO with the yml file in my project. I tried but bean is not binding with the yml file entries.

As far as I know `@ConfigurationProperties`is part of *SpringBoot* features only.

Please give your useful suggestion.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940583/can-i-manually-load-configurationproperties-without-the-spring-appcontext/39774535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like for example below:

if your  yml file has properties containing **same** prefix then you could use as below:

**POJO class:**

```
@Configuration // add this if your spring boot version is < 2.2 or else please donot add.
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.db.props") //example
public class MyPojoProps{ 

    private String userName; 
    private int password; 
    private String uri; 

    // standard getters and setters 
}
```

your application.yml may be something like below:

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  db:
   props:
     userName:
     password:
     uri:
```

[Please refer here for more information](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: I had to provide the application.yml file location as well.