# How to manually bind ConfigurationProperties to a bean / create bean from ConfigurationProperties in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans

I use Spring Boot for a project, where configuration files are bound to a bean via

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="foo.bar", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
class myBean{
  private String propertyA;
  private String propertyB;
  ...
}
```

This works quite well, the properties are filled in a process that does not matter much for this problem - it just provides the properties of the prefix defined in the annotation.

However, I would like to create another bean of the same class and have it filled with properties from another file.

Ideally, this would be something like

```
MyBean otherBean = (MyBean) WhatEverClass.createBeanFromProperties(MyBean.class, Properties myPropertiesFromSomeOtherFile);
```

Is there some Class which is able to this Properties-to-Bean Mapping?

I have searched for Classes which could implement this functionality.
DefaultListableBeanFactory only provides already created Beans but I have no method to point Spring to a specific property file for this bean (except for changing the annotation, but I need the prefix mapped to this bean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following methods. [Can I manually load @ConfigurationProperties without the Spring AppContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60335339/9304033)

```java
Properties myPropertiesFromSomeOtherFile = ...;

ConfigurationPropertySource propertySource = new MapConfigurationPropertySource(myPropertiesFromSomeOtherFile);
Binder binder = new Binder(propertySource);

MyBean myBean = binder.bind("foo.bar", MyBean.class).get();
```