# How to pass a complex object in application.properties file in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

Is there a way I can pass a complex object in the application.properties file as a key value pair where the value of the key would be a json and then read that in my Java class?
Ex I want to pass something similar to the below json structure:

```
[
   {
      "property": "description",
      "value": "This is a description",
      "required": true
   },
   {
      "property": "link",
      "value": "This is a link",
      "required": false
   }
]
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-json-properties

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks for pointing this. But in case do you know if something similar could be done with the properties file instead of adding a json file and then reading it?

Comment: You could add in your properties file something like `description: value :"This is a description"`(check some yaml example for exact syntax), and then read it in a class annotated with `Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, you want to extract Java object from a YML (or properties) config?

An approach would be to use Spring's `@ConfigurationProperties`, see [Spring Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html), [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) or [Baeldung's explanations](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot).

For the same but programatically, see [Can I manually load @ConfigurationProperties without the Spring AppContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940583/can-i-manually-load-configurationproperties-without-the-spring-appcontext) and currently the answers from *ctranxuan* or *lemonzone2010*